# Passing Data through NSTimer UserInfo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I am trying to pass data through userInfo for an NSTimer call. What is the best way to do this? I am trying to use an NSDictionary, this is simple enough when I have Objective-C objects, but what about other data? I want to do something like this, which doesn't work as is:

```
- (void)play:(SystemSoundID)sound target:(id)target callbackSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSLog(@"pause ipod");
    [iPodController pause];
    theSound = sound;

    NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [cb setObject:(id)&sound forKey:@"sound"];
    [cb setObject:target forKey:@"target"];
    [cb setObject:(id)&selector forKey:@"selector"];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(notifyPause1:)
                                   userInfo:(id)cb
                                    repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: Is `cb` nil when you get to `-notifyPause1:`?

Answer (score 53):

You have to wrap the information correctly into the dictionary:

```
- (void) play:(SystemSoundID)sound target:(id)target callbackSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSLog(@"pause ipod");
    [iPodController pause];
    theSound = sound;

    NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [cb setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sound] forKey:@"sound"];
    [cb setObject:target forKey:@"target"];
    [cb setObject:NSStringFromSelector(selector) forKey:@"selector"];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(notifyPause1:)
                                   userInfo:cb 
                                     repeats:NO];
    [cb release];

}
```

In `notifyPause1:`, you retrieve everything:

```
- (void)notifyPause1:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];

    SystemSoundID sound = [[dict objectForKey:@"sound"] intValue];
    id target = [dict objectForKey:@"target"];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([dict objectForKey:@"selector"]);

    // Do whatever...
}
```

As the timer is a repeating timer, you do not need the dictionary anymore, so you can release it.

Comment: A heads up - if you do call *invalidate* for your NSTimer, make sure to check *isValid* flag before accessing *userInfo*. This is stated in the docs for *userInfo* property, and I just got caught a crash in that exact place.

Answer (score 7):

Your call is right, but you don't have to cast the dictionary to id. You can get the userInfo back with the following line in your notifyPause1: method:

```
- (void)notifyPause1:(NSTimer *)timer {

    NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may ask for the timer in the method given to the selector,

Then you can grab useInfo from that timer (**timer.userInfo**):

```
- (void)settingTimer
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kYourTimeInterval
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                               userInfo:yourObject
                                repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
  id yourObject = theTimer.userInfo;
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sound` and `selector` aren't Objective-C objects: `sound` is an unsigned number and `selector` is a pointer to a C struct . That's likely to cause a crash of some sort.

You'll want to use NSValue to hold the value for `selector` and NSNumber to hold the value for `sound`. NSValue and NSNumber are objects and will work with the NSMutableDictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Laurent Etiemble's method  works well for making good use of timer methods in subclasses of UIViewcontroller which can be easily used in a number of different view controllers.

Below is a way to write a generic score display which can be used over and over in the same app by passing the view through NSTimer userInfo.

.h (subclass of UIViewcontroller)

```
  - (NSTimeInterval) timeSet;
  - (void) timeRun: (UISegmentedControl*)scoreDisplay;
  - (void) timeWrite: (NSTimer *)timer;
```

.m

```
            - (NSTimeInterval) timeSet {
                return [self.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
            }

            - (void) timeWrite: (NSTimer *)timer
            {
                NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];
                UISegmentedControl *scoreDisplay = [dict objectForKey:@"scoreDisplay"];

                int myint = round([self timeSet]);
                NSString* buttonWrite = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.answered] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Errors: %d", self.errors]] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Time: %d", (myint*-1)]];

                [scoreDisplay setTitle:buttonWrite forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            }

            - (void) timeRun: (UISegmentedControl*)scoreDisplay
            {
                self.startTime = [NSDate date];

                NSMutableDictionary *cb = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [cb setObject:scoreDisplay forKey:@"scoreDisplay"];

                self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(timeWrite:)
                                                              userInfo:cb
                                                               repeats:YES];

            }
```

In the view controller

.m

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       //load ScoreDisplay
       [self timeRun:self.scoreDisplay];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not cast your objects to id when assigning to the dictionary. Any object that can be embedded directly into a `NSDictionary` already derives from `NSObject` and are implicitly concidered cast to id.
Store the name of the selector as an `NSString` (using `NSStringFromSelector()`) and then convert it back to a selector using `NSSelectorFromString()`

Claus